# python Fabric API: No hosts found

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, fabric

I am running the following fabric command:

1. `fab -f fabfile_awsgpu.py -R mygpu ssh`
2. `fab -f fabfile_awsgpu.py -R mygpu cuda_setup8 anaconda_setup tf_setup keras_setup torch_preroll torch_setup_solo`

The first command prints the correct `env.host_string`, while the second command prints that `env.host_string` is `None`, with a message below:

```
No hosts found. Please specify (single) host string for connection:
```

While does this happen? fabfile_awsgpu is below:

```
env.roledefs.update(get_target_instance())
#env.hosts = ['ec2-35-167-153-191.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com']
#env.disable_known_hosts = True

@task
def launch():

    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name=AWS_REGION)

    BlockDeviceMappings=[
        {
            'DeviceName': '/dev/xvda',
            'Ebs': {
                'VolumeSize': 600,
                'DeleteOnTermination': True,
                'VolumeType': 'standard',
                'SnapshotId' : 'snap-c87f35ec'
            },
        },
    ]

    instances = ec2.create_instances(ImageId=tgt_ami, MinCount=1, MaxCount=1,
                                     KeyName=my_aws_key, InstanceType=INSTANCE_TYPE,
                                     BlockDeviceMappings = BlockDeviceMappings,
                                     EbsOptimized=True
    )

    inst = instances[0]
    print inst

    inst.wait_until_running()
    inst.reload()
    inst.create_tags(
        Resources=[
            inst.instance_id
        ],
        Tags=[
            {
                'Key': 'Name',
                'Value': instance_name
            },
        ]
    )
    @task
    def ssh():
        print env.host_string
        local("ssh -A " + env.host_string)


    @task
    def tensorboard():
        local("open http://"+env.host_string+":6006")

    @task
    def copy_model():
        local("scp " + env.host_string+":/tmp/model.ckpt /tmp/")

    @task
    def basic_setup():
        print env.host_string
        print env.hosts
        run("sudo yum update -q -y")
        run("sudo yum groupinstall 'Development Tools' -q -y")
        run("sudo yum install -q -y emacs tmux  gcc g++ dstat htop")
        run("sudo yum install -y kernel-devel-`uname -r`")
```

Comment: is this full message ? maybe there is more usefull information. Did you try to use `print()` to see when and where in code is the problem ?

Comment: Why do you have task declarations nested inside of the `launch` task? What about the other tasks - cuda_setup8, anaconda_setup, tf_setup, keras_setup, torch_preroll, torch_setup_solo - where are those? They're not declared in the code you've provided. Can you break this down into a simpler case, rather than including these commands that are specific to your project? Also note that if you're using the `@roles` decorator on any of your tasks, then the command-line value will be ignored (docs on that: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.0.0/usage/execution.html#order-of-precedence)